# Creating Parameter field for # of days

Tags: crystal-reports

In crystal reports I am trying to create a parameter where the user can enter number of days.
For example, I want the report to prompt with Enter Age Days: XX
The issue with this is that I do not have a field that stores days in the database. I just want the end user to be able to enter a number lets say 60, then store that number so that it can be used in report calculations.

Please let me know your thoughts 
Thank you
Sarah

Creating number type parameter that is not linked to a database field

Answer (score 0):

Parameters in Crystal don't have to be 'dynamic' (linked to data source column).

When you create a new parameter, the default is for a 'static' parameter. 
Simply set the data type of the parameter to numeric and name it.